# Where to place additional libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, uislider

I have a webpage in which I am currently using the FLOT library, but I also need to add the JQuery UI slider. I have downloaded the library. Where should I place the library in my folders? Currently, I have the library in the same folder as my HTML/Javascript files, but the slider does not appear after I write the code (same code from the website).

Comment: Give more details on where your lib files are located, and how you include those files.

Comment: C:\Users\speaker\flot-flot-e2147c0\examples\basic-usage

Comment: In basic-usage, I have my HTML file as well as the library

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest putting the file next to your *jquery.min.js* file, which you might want to put in **./js** subfolder. The important thing is to load the lirbary from your html.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where you put the library as long as you call it in your script.

```
 <script src="wherethefilelives/file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical directory structure one might use.

- `app_name`

  - `scripts`

    - `lib`
  - `stylesheets`
  - `images`

With the HTML files in the `app_name` directory.

So it is common to place all external libraries in a separate `lib` sub-directory within the `scripts` directory.

That being said, your end users may have a better experience if you actually use a CDN for common external libraries. This can speed things up for a few different reasons. Check out this article to learn more about it: http://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-use-a-cdn/.

And here is a CDN for the FLOT library: //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.min.js.